# How to use AT commands in Android applications?

Tags: java, android

I want to send AT commands in my Android application, but I could not find the right syntax. How can I do this?

Comment: Erm, what do you want to send AT commands to?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this, i'm trying to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The invokeOemRilRequestRaw() and invokeOemRilRequestStrings() methods which have implementations in a number of classes (RIL, PhoneProxy, PhoneBase, and some others) are what you need, but they are not available through the SDK and thus off-limits to us mere mortals.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a great review of this in the XDA forum thread:

   [*How to talk to the Modem with AT commands*](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1471241).

   That thread show you how to send AT commands (ATC) with a remote 
   terminal (USB connected to you PC), but it has not yet solved the 
   problem of how to use a local (phone) terminal to talk to the 
   phone Modem.
2. You need a terminal application/program to do any talking to the
   modem (remember, its a 2-way communication). So that's why you need
   a rooted device, since the root kit usually come with *Busybox*
   (that includes a *microcom* terminal program). Otherwise you have to
   write your own program.
3. AFAIK. You can disconnect incoming calls in many other and easier 
   ways than with AT commands.

Answer (score -1):

Use syntax like this and let me know:

```
echo -e "AT+CFUN=?\r\n" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Thanks balaji duddukuri.....


but can you please explain how to embed this AT command syntax in android (java) code.
actually i want to disconnect incoming call programmatically for which i want to use AT+CHUP command but nnot getting how to execute this in java code.

Comment: Can we use RIL (Radio Interface Layer) to disconnect incoming call ??
please reply..
Thanks